# Single "list" component vs. repeated individual components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm just learning Vue and following a course that repeatedly shows examples of taking some sample data, then creating a single component that uses a `v-for` directive to iterate over the data and create markup for each data item.

It strikes me a bit odd because my instinct would be to create a component that represents a single data item, then create an instance for each item.  Each instance would be able to react to its own data mutations, emit its own events, etc.  That being said, it doesn't seem difficult to do this within a single "ItemList" component and dynamically pass in values, but it just doesn't sit right with me for some reason.

My question is:  Is it even possible to create one parent component that can iterate over some data and instantiate multiple instances of another component that represents a single data item?

My experience thus far is that any given component is imported and you have access to that one component, so I'm not even certain that it's possible to have multiple instances of a given component.  And given the answer to my previous question, is it a best practice to do it that way or just use a single component to loop over all of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `<component></component>` helper that Vue provides to you.

```
<component v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="`rows-${index}`"
           :is="RowRenderer"
           :row="row"></component>
```

You would write that in the template of the parent component, where the parent component includes the `RowRenderer` component:

```
components: {
  RowRenderer
}
```